# Pass GET variables without the URL?

Tags: javascript, post, get

Suppose I have these two links on my homepage

http://example.com/user?id=1

http://example.com/user?id=1&sex=male

These two links point to the same page. The users page loads information based on the id.
If the second link is clicked the page loads extra information based on sex.

These two pages are almost identical, therefore not good for SEO.

My question is it possible to pass the second argument without using the url?

Maybe using POST or javascript?

Thanks

Comment: yes it is possible to pass it using AJAX, are you familiar with jquery?

Comment: its not good for SEO because search engines will crawl both links and end up indexing two pages even though they contain the same content. This will end as duplicate content.

Comment: jquery maybe, javascript not so much. But I will have go, if you can show me the ropes.

Answer (score 0):

Using POST is the answear. Even though I have no idea, how this influences any SEO strategies...

Comment: Does using POST involve some sort of dummy form? Because that will not be good at all.

Answer (score 0):

The only other way to pass it without GET would be POST or by using cookies. They may be other methods that I am missing, and please correct my if I am wrong.